# Specifying a foreign key Id in a model in EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I noticed that in EntityFramework if I setup my models like the following:

Author can have many books, but a book can only have one Author...

**Author**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
```

**Book:**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
```

**DbContext:**

```
public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
```

I noticed that when the database is generated the tables look like the following:

**Author**

```
Id
... other fields
```

**Book**

```
Id
AuthorId (foreign key)
... other fields
```

**My Question:**

I see that even though I didn't specify the foreign key AuthorId in my Book model, entity framework automatically knew to go and create it. Additionally, if I go to save a new Author and populate it's Books property with a couple of books, then add to context and save it will Automatically save everything correctly - filling in the AuthorId foreign key field automatically.

This is great, but I am wondering if it would be alright if I actually did add the AuthorId foreign key to my Book model. The reason being because in my code there might be a scenario where I want to add a Book without actually having an Author object first. Is it normal to do this and is adding AuthorId to the Book model the correct thing to do here? I am aware that I could also add an actual Author object as a property to my Book model also. Just trying to figure out in what scenario I should do what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to your question, Adding AuthoerID in books object is perfect solution. Keep Books object in Author may over consume the memory when you load author information.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks, I am starting to realize now after asking the question that there is nothing wrong with adding an AuthorId field to my Book model. Additionally, I can add an Author object to my Book model too if I want the entire thing to be bound when pulling from the database.